# Concatenating NumPy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I want to start off with an empty NumPy array, and then add rows to it sequentially (all rows are the same length). However, at the start, I do not know the length of the rows, nor do I know how many rows I will be adding. How can I do this?

So for my three rows:

```
a = np.array([1, 1, 1])
b = np.array([2, 2, 2])
c = np.array([3, 3, 3])
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
x = []
x = np.concatenate(x, a)
x = np.concatenate(x, b)
x = np.concatenate(x, c)
```

This did not work, because it concatenates `a` and `b` into a single array of length 6, rather than an array of size (2, 3).
Any help?

Comment: "I want to start off with an empty NumPy array, and then add rows to it sequentially" - that turns out to be an atrociously inefficient way to work with NumPy arrays. If you can't build the array in one go, accumulate the rows in a list and then stick the rows together in one step at the end.

Comment: That's not how you call `concatenate`.  You provide it with a list of the arrays that you want to join.  The 2nd argument to concatenate is the `axis`.

Answer (score 2):

Collect all rows in a list and then use `vstack`:

```
a = np.array([1, 1, 1])
b = np.array([2, 2, 2])
c = np.array([3, 3, 3])
x = np.vstack([a,b,c])
```

Comment: For this `np.array([a,b,c])` also works, as does `np.stack([a,b,c], axis=0)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting with

```
x = []
```

you can say

```
x = numpy.zeros([0, 3])    # 2-dimensional array with 0 rows and 3 columns
```

and then add rows this way:

```
x = numpy.vstack([x, a])
x = numpy.vstack([x, b])
x = numpy.vstack([x, c])
```

...but as user2357112 pointed out, it's much more efficient to start with a list, do `x.append(each_array)`, and only concatenate the list of arrays into a single `numpy.ndarray` right at the end:

```
x = []
x.append(a)
x.append(b)
x.append(c)
x = numpy.vstack(x)
```

NB: `numpy.concatenate([x,a])` was working in the direction you didn't expect because, although the default direction for `numpy.concatenate` is indeed `axis=0`, which is conventionally thought of as the row-to-row direction in 2-d arrays,  your arrays `a`, `b` and `c` are ***not*** 2-d arrays and therefore cannot be thought of as single "rows" to start with.  They only ***have*** dimension 0, so their existing elements vary along dimension 0—the same dimension along which you're concatenating.   To do what you intend, you would either have to define them using double brackets to start with, as in `a = numpy.array([[1,1,1]])`  or convert them from their existing 1-dimensional state by saying `b = b[numpy.newaxis, :]` before concatenation.  `numpy.vstack` does the latter for you implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html). It's more general than `numpy.vstack` or `numpy.hstack` because it allows you to select the axis over which you are concatenating vectors/matrices/arrays.

Example:

```
>>> X, Y, Z, T = numpy.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(4, 3, 1), dtype='I')
>>> numpy.concatenate((X, Y, Z, T), axis=1)
array([[0, 7, 1, 7],
       [8, 4, 7, 7],
       [1, 9, 9, 7]], dtype=uint32)
```